# In a firebird database I get empty table after some operations

Tags: c#, .net, firebird

In my application there is one table that there is only one operation executed:
update or insert.

After performing certain operations and validating/repairing database (don't know if that is the reason), that table becomes empty ...

What kind of operations could potentially result in "truncating the table"?

Thanks!

Comment: A 'repair' could potentially empty a table if all datapages are corrupted, but as that is a rare occurrence, you really need to provide a lot more detail (including how you 'repair' and why).

Comment: Also make sure that your application doesn't recreate or redeploy the database under certain conditions (eg incorrect use of EntityFramework initializers/migrations)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Furthermore We have noticed that: several tables are also empty and also all relations (FK) and PK on all tables had vanished .... Could some operation of the firebird's libraries do it?

Comment: Check your firebird.log. Any warnings/errors? Also you can add on delete trigger, to record any delete into custom log table.

Comment: @John Only if your application executes DDL or messes with the system tables. There is nothing in Firebird that will automagically delete your tables or foreign keys (except possibly a `gfix -mend` when your database is already severely corrupted)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can the following scenario occour? We set via system table column from null to not null. That table has some null records on that column. Firebird accepts it. Then later we validate database, it fails so we backup the db and restore. Backup is performed smoothly, but restoring process starts recreating the structure (firstly tables) and then it stops on the table when there are null values. The reuslts is I have only clear tables without relations, most of them are empty. Can I have half-restored db? (I work not in service but local db mode)

Comment: @John Yes that is entirely possible. You should not make changes through the system tables because certain checks are not made, and if you make changes like this (to `not null`), then you need to update all columns so they are correctly populated. When restoring a database it is important to 1) pay attention to errors and 2) never restore over an existing database, but restore to a different name and only delete the old when restore was successful (and rename the new to the right name).